# Using Ethereum puppeth in raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2, arm, cryptocurrency

I have installed geth(go ethereum) client on a Raspberry Pi 2 using the below steps.

```
wget https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds/geth-linux-arm7-1.8.2-b8b9f7f4.tar.gz

tar -xvf geth-linux-arm7-1.8.2-b8b9f7f4.tar.gz

cp geth-linux-arm7-1.8.2-b8b9f7f4 /usr/local/bin/
```

Geth is working without any issues but I am not able to use puppeth client. When 
I execute puppeth it does not give any output. Please help.

Comment: Isn't the tar ball a source packet and you have to `configure`, `make` and `make install` it? Are there files named `README` and `INSTALL`?

Comment: @Ingo the tar file which I downloaded was binary and not source. Should I download the source and the do make install?

Comment: No, it's ok then. But sorry, I'm not familiar with this and cannot see a specific problem with raspberry pi.

Comment: @Aurora0001 You are right, have mixed up comment and answer ;-). Have deleted the answer and give a comment.